# Will google home mini work in foreign country (not supported)?

Tags: google-home

If I buy a google home in US and give it to a friend in Ethiopia, will it work if he speaks English to it or will the Ethiopian IP address cause an issue with the functionality of the google home device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a colleague bring me a Google Home from the US on release day to the UK and it worked just fine before they were released in the UK.

The  only problem may be that some Google Assistant Actions will not work as they will be limited to certain geographical regions. Also there may be limitations based on where the Google id used with it is registered.